# rails default sort using MetaSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, meta-search

I am using the gem metasearch to provide some sorting features. The page is defaulting to a sort of `created_at ASC`, but I want it to be `created_at DESC`, but I can't explicitly state that because it will override MetaSearch's sort features.

```
def index
  @search = Photo.search(params[:search])
end
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and ended up doing like this in the controller

```
search = {"meta_sort" => "created_at.desc"}.merge(params[:search] || {})
@search = Photo.search(search)
```

Default sort order is created_at DESC, but it will be overwritten if a new sort order is received in the params. Seems to work for me.

Comment: cleaner way as for me
`params[:search] ||= { 'meta_sort' => 'created_at.desc' }
@search = Photo.metasearch(params[:search])`

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach. It works for me:

```
def index
  @search = Photo.search(params[:search])
  @photos = @search.order("created_at desc")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@search = Photo.search(params[:search])

@search.meta_sort = 'your_column.desc'